# ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty in Apache and wsgi_mod

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy Django project on Apache and wsgi_mod in Windows 10. What I did so far:

**1. Added following in httpd.conf of Apache conf folder**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/apps/django/django_projects/project/egeirn/wsgi.py"

WSGIPythonPath "C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/apps/django/django_projects/project;C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/python/Lib/site-packages"

<Directory "C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/apps/django/django_projects/project/egeirn">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

**2. Following is the content of my wsgi.py file:**

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/apps/django/django_projects/project')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "egeirn.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I start the Apache server, it gives the following error in logs file:

```
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236] mod_wsgi (pid=916): Target WSGI script 'C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/apps/django/django_projects/project/egeirn/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236] mod_wsgi (pid=916): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/apps/django/django_projects/project/egeirn/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]   File "C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.10.1-0/apps/django/django_projects/project/egeirn/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>, referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]     application = get_wsgi_application(), referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]   File "C:\\Bitnami\\djangostack-1.10.1-0\\apps\\django\\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application, referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]     django.setup(set_prefix=False), referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]   File "C:\\Bitnami\\djangostack-1.10.1-0\\apps\\django\\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\__init__.py", line 22, in setup, referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING), referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]   File "C:\\Bitnami\\djangostack-1.10.1-0\\apps\\django\\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__, referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]     self._setup(name), referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]   File "C:\\Bitnami\\djangostack-1.10.1-0\\apps\\django\\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup, referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module), referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]   File "C:\\Bitnami\\djangostack-1.10.1-0\\apps\\django\\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 116, in __init__, referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty."), referer: http://localhost:82/
[Thu Nov 03 17:47:11.328063 2016] [:error] [pid 916:tid 1236] [client ::1:63236] ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty., referer: http://localhost:82/
```

I am using [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) to read .env file and keep configurations in environment variables. Although I have my `SECRET_KEY` in the `base.py` file

I have used it like this in `base.py` file:

```
import environ
# three folder back (/project/egeirn/settings/ - 3 = /)
root = environ.Path(__file__) - 3

# set default values and casting
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False),)

# reading .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../config/.env'))

SITE_ROOT = root()

# Raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

This is my `.env` file:

```
SECRET_KEY=<MY_SECRET_KEY_HERE>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here, how come it cannot read the `SECRET_KEY`?

Thanks

Comment: What is this `environ` you are using in `import environ`?

Comment: I am using [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) to read .env file and keep configurations in environment variables